# Mouseup after Draging without library

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mouseup, onmouseup

I have some pure css snap scroll functionality and I want to detect where an element is relative to the viewport after the user stop dragging.
The thing is I don't wan't to use some fancy library because I don't need to actually move or drop something.
I just wan't to fire an event on mouseup. My problem is that the mouseup event won't fire after I moved my cursor while having the left mouse button pressed.
Btw. I'm using Vu3

`<span id="handle" class="card-handle" onmouseup="myMethod"></span>`

I hope to find a lightweight solution, scince I don't really need all this dragging functionality

Comment: `onmouseup` event will get fired only when you release the mouse button over an element

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can try something like

```
<span id="handle" class="card-handle" ondragend="myFunction(event)" draggable="true"></span>
```

and in your methods

```
methods: {
   myFunction() {
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    var coor = "Coordinates: (" + x + "," + y + ")";
    console.log(cor);
  }
}
```